# Finding parameters which reveal clustering in t-SNE

Tags: clustering, pca, tsne

These data are from [SAMHSA, Mental Health Client-Level Data](https://www.datafiles.samhsa.gov/dataset/mental-health-client-level-data-2021-mh-cld-2021-ds0001). I am trying to find the right parameters to obtain clustering as in [this paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6783390/). Code [here](https://github.com/jacksonwalters/ml-examples/).

For now, I'm dropping columns which aren't disorders. I expect life factors (employment, insurance, housing status, etc.) to be correlated.

I'm using [this tool](https://distill.pub/2016/misread-tsne/) to understand t-SNE better. I'm playing with the perplexity.

num_data_points=500,000 (6.5mil total),
num_cols = 50,
num_iters = 500,
perplexity = 50

[image: t-sne plot of disorders and life factors]

Is there any trick to reveal better clusters?